# Set new field to true/false if an array contains a specific value or not

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If `$myDogsName` is in the array `dogNamesOfWinnersArray` then `myDogWins` should be `true` if its not in the array it should be `false`.

Is this even possible?

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: { myDogWins: { $myDogsName: [ "$dogNamesOfWinnersArray", [] ] } }
        }
    ])
```

the array looks like

```
dogNamesOfWinnersArray: [
        {
            "name" : "jake", 
            "age" : 6, 
            "breed" : "Bulldog", 
            ...
        },
        {
            "name" : "fred", 
            "age" : 8, 
            "breed" : "Bulldog",
            ... 
        },

    ]
```

`$myDogsName` is `jake` so I expect `myDogWins` to be `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator is what you need.

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "myDogWins": {
      "$in": [
        "$myDogsName",
        "$dogNamesOfWinnersArray.name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$myDogsName` is just a string, `$dogNamesOfWinnersArray` is an array and the name can be found at `$dogNamesOfWinnersArray.name`

Comment: If I understand, the array elements are subdocuments. Is that correct?

Comment: I updated my question for clarity, how do I add `name` on the end of `dogNamesOfWinnersArray`

Comment: I've tried to run it but I get no data back at all, I feel that `$dogNamesOfWinnersArray.name` needs to be somthing like `$dogNamesOfWinnersArray[x].name` where x is the iterator?

Comment: No indexing. [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DtPyQSk2lbF)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.dogs.save( { _id: 1, name: "jake" } )
db.dogs.save( { _id: 2, name: "jake2" } )

db.dogs.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          dogNamesOfWinnersArray: { 
              $concatArrays: [ [ ], dogNamesOfWinnersArray ] 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          myDogWins: { $in: [ "$name", "$dogNamesOfWinnersArray.name" ] } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { dogNamesOfWinnersArray: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "jake", "myDogWins" : true }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "jake2", "myDogWins" : false }
```